# Is there any symmetry in this opamp ckt?

Tags: operational-amplifier

By thevenizing the at the inverting input, I notice that when the variable resistor equals \$R_2\$ the output \$v_{out}\$ becomes \$0\$. Can this result be "seen" with out doing the algebra?

I feel there is some symmetry but I couldn't quite figure it out. The top \$R_2\$ resistor is connected to \$v_{out}\$ but the bottom variable resistor is tied to ground. This is throwing me off. Any help?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. With negative feedback the circuit should stabilise at a state where \$ V_- = V_+ \$. The question then is simply what output voltage will achieve that for a given input signal.

To make the maths easy we'll assume that all resistors are equal values.

- Since \$ R_1 = R_{var} \$ we know that \$ V_+ = \frac {V_{in}} 2 \$.
- Therefore \$ V_- = \frac {V_{in}} 2 \$.

The only way this can happen is when \$ V_{out} = 0 \$.

I would then start to mentally adjust the variable resistor and consider what needs to happen to maintain balance.

- If we adjust to half the value of R1 then \$ V_+ = \frac {V_{in}} 3 \$.
- To achieve stability again the output needs to move to pull \$ V_- =  \frac {V_{in}} 3 \$. This will happen when the voltage across R1, \$ V_{R1} = \frac 2 3 V_{in} \$ and the same across R2 meaning that \$ V_{out} = -\frac 1 3 V_{in} \$.

Comment: @becca, I recommend that you unaccept until the Earth revolves once or twice so that you give the whole of humanity a chance to answer. You'll get different insights than mine whereas the "accept" may discourage others. You can, of course, re-accept mine when nothing better comes along.

Comment: Haha I'll give it some time. Immediately it became clear after seeing your answer that keeping the vout = 0 and \$R_{var}\$=R2  makes the circuit symmetrical. Thank you somuch:))

Comment: On secondary reading I see the complexity in your analysis. You seem to be using virtual short between the inputs and forcing the voltages \$V_{+}=V_{-}\$. I get it now. Thanks again:)

Comment: I think you've got it! Just remember, on first analysis of a circuit to check that it will drive itself into a "virtual short". I suggest that you compare this to an op-amp Schmitt trigger which doesn't behave like this. Then have a look at TI's http://www.ti.com/lit/ug/tidu020a/tidu020a.pdf which may be of interest.

Answer (score 1):

When R1/R2 = R1/VR1 the voltages at the two inputs of the opamp will be equal if Vout = 0.

If Vin+ = Vin- Vout will be zero.